# Cmake - error while loading shared libraries: libXXX.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I am compiling a C++ Program.
When I compile it on my machine the program runs just fine.
When I zip the whole build and send it over to friend he gets the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libCommon.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Somehow I believe that the shared library is not properly linked.

Here is my main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Vibranium_Core)

#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(FLATBUFFERS_MAX_PARSING_DEPTH 16)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)

if(APPLE)
    set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include")
endif()

if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")
    execute_process(
            COMMAND git rev-list --count HEAD
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_VERSION
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    execute_process(
            COMMAND git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_BRANCH
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    execute_process(
            COMMAND git log -1 --format=%h
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_HASH
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    execute_process(
            COMMAND git --no-pager log -1 --format=%ai
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_RELEASED_ON
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
else(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")
    set(GIT_BRANCH "")
    set(GIT_COMMIT_HASH "")
endif(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")

message(STATUS "VibraniumCore current branch: ${GIT_BRANCH}")
message(STATUS "VibraniumCore Version: ${GIT_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "VibraniumCore commit hash: ${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}")
message(STATUS "Released on: ${GIT_RELEASED_ON}")

message(STATUS "Generating version.h")

configure_file(
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/version.h.in
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Common/Version.h
)

add_definitions(-DGIT_COMMIT_HASH="${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}")
add_definitions(-DGIT_BRANCH="${GIT_BRANCH}")
add_definitions(-DGIT_VERSION="${GIT_VERSION}")
add_definitions(-DGIT_RELEASED_ON="${GIT_RELEASED_ON}")

if("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" EQUAL "8")
    message(STATUS "Target is 64 bits")
    if (WIN32)
        set(WINXXBITS Win64)
    endif(WIN32)
else("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" EQUAL "8")
    message(STATUS "Target is 32 bits")
    if (WIN32)
        set(WINXXBITS Win32)
    endif(WIN32)
endif("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" EQUAL "8")

# set macro-directory
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/macros")

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
find_package(MySQL REQUIRED)
find_package(Flatbuffers REQUIRED
        PATHS /usr/local/flatbuffers)
        
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR})
if(APPLE)
include_directories(/opt/homebrew/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
endif()
# set default buildoptions and print them
include(cmake/options.cmake)

# Find revision ID and hash of the sourcetree
include(cmake/genrev.cmake)

# print out the results before continuing
include(cmake/showoptions.cmake)

# add dependencies
add_subdirectory(dep)

# add libraries and projects
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Common)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/WorldServer)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/AuthServer)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/ClientEmulator)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/GameServerClientEmulator)
add_subdirectory(Tests)


set_target_properties(VibraniumCoreTests PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
set_target_properties(gtest PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
set_target_properties(gmock PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
set_target_properties(gtest_main PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
set_target_properties(gmock_main PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)

set_target_properties(
        Common WorldServer AuthServer ClientEmulator
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib"
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib"
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
```

Any idea why I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Everything is properly linked. This is precisely what shared libraries are for: so that they don't need to bloat the executable, and are installed separately. The shared libraries must be separately installed in order to run an executable that links to them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik should I changed the library to not be shared ?

Comment: That's up to you to decide, the decision should be guided based on the specific application requirements, and how everything is supposed to work, I have insufficient information to make that decision myself. That's one option. Another option is to package the shared library together. Another option would be to learn how to use the operating system's package manager to automatically resolve shared library dependencies and install any needed libraries automatically. There could be other options, too.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how can I pack a shared lib with the package ? Basically I have it build /bin/lib/libCommon.so but it looks like the executable is not reading it from there. It searches is from the system instead of the packed and build .so file. Any idea ?

Comment: Why be inconsistent with repeating the condition in `else()` and `endif()` commands? The requirement to repeat the condition there was removed a long time ago...

Comment: If you want to distribute your library and executable to other computer, then you need to learn RPATH mechanism: it is responsible for search the library when the program is run. About setting RPATH in CMake see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling. Note, that for a CMake project its **build tree** is NOT intended to be distributed. Instead **install** the project (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Installing%20and%20Testing.html) and distribute the **installation tree**. CMake has nice support for packaging, read about CPack.

Comment: BTW, using `$ORIGIN` as RPATH implies that an executable will be able to find a library located in the **same directory** as executable. However, your executable is built into `bin/` subdirectory, but the libraries are built into `bin/lib/` subdirectory (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#output-artifacts) about what artifacts are controlled by LIBRARY and RUNTIME).

Comment: @Tsyvarev can you provide cmake install example in answer so I can accept it ?